# What will be impact on billing, if I delete some files from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm confused. I am storing files of users for limited time (like stories and status), and now my Firebase Storage is full of old files that are useless files. If I delete these old files from Firebase Storage, what will be the impact on my billing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) shows that you pay $0.026/GB per month for storage space occupied on Cloud Storage.

So once you delete files, you pay as much less as the amount of data you deleted.